# Google Play Services SDK (version 38) update

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, google-play-services

First of all: I am a Software Testing Engineer, so I don't create applications. I use Android Studio for AVD creation, than I install already developed apk file on Android Emulator and make tests. About a month ago I have noticed an annoying pop-up "Update Google Play services" and when I clicked "Update" button - nothing happened.

I don't want to describe all my struggles, but finally I decided that root cause is the outdated Google Play Services SDK (now I have version 38). Android Studio doesn't offers me to update it, and also I can't find any information about version 39. Maybe you know something about this and can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can always check [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases) the latest version of Google Play service. This is the official documentation of Google Play service that shows you the update and the highlights of each version. This [page](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) also shows you how to use the Google Play services APIs in the Android studio.

Note that to test your app using the Google Play services SDK, you must use either:

- A compatible Android device that runs Android 2.3 or higher and includes Google Play Store.
- The Android emulator with an AVD that runs the Google APIs platform based on Android 4.2.2 or higher.